# ActionPerformed event in a class file

Tags: java

I have created some buttons in jframe and set ActionListener to it manually in a single ActionPerformed event. and then created one separate class file as (server, thats my project requirement) and wants to perofrm same activity from this class asls but i am unable to have click events for those buttons which i have added from class.

Comment: Provide your code please.

Comment: please post the code